# Do I need a comma after which in this sentence?

Tags: commas

Do I need commas around "*on that morning*"?  While technically correct (I believe), it just seems like so many commas sounds too choppy if one pauses at each comma.

> As they passed the cathedral, they rode alongside the River Irwell,
>   which, on that morning, had a thick layer of fog blanketing the black
>   waters.

Comment: That sentence sounds like it came from a 19th century novel, where it was punctuated properly for its time. I'd recommend they be left out in the 21st century.

Answer (score 5):

You can dispense with most of the commas in that sentence. You should keep the comma before *which*, as the usual style is to put a comma before a [non-restrictive relative clause,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Restrictive_or_non-restrictive_relative_clauses) and there is no reason to make an exception here. You could also put an (optional) comma after "cathedral", as when you're speaking there's a pause there, and style guides suggest putting a comma after an [introductory clause](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/) in sentences. (Exceptions should be made for short prepositional phrases; this one is long enough that a comma is probably better.) I don't see any real reason to set off *"on that morning"* with commas, although doing so wouldn't be ungrammatical. However, adding those two extra commas makes the sentence very choppy.

This gives:

> As they passed the cathedral, they rode alongside the River Irwell, which on that morning had a thick layer of fog blanketing the black waters.

Comment: Very choppy, or a deliberate metre.

Comment: Deliberate...from a novel based in 1904.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need them. You can keep them if you want to imply that it is a [parenthetical element](http://realgrammar.wordpress.com/commas/with-parenthetical-elements/): a part of a sentence that can be removed without changing the essential meaning of that sentence.

> As they passed the cathedral, they rode alongside the River Irwell 
>   which, on that morning, had a thick layer of fog blanketing the black
>   waters.

You can do without them if you feel that it is essential (it is a *judgement call*) or if you consider it just as a *temporal adverb*, which it probably is. You can drop all commas you like, and leave just the one after *cathedral*. A comma is **necessary** there (and not 'optional', as suggested in another answer) as the subordinate clause precedes the main one [see here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/subordinate-clauses-and-commas/).

> As they passed the cathedral, they rode alongside the River Irwell 
>   which on that morning had a thick layer of fog blanketing the black
>   waters.

This solution gives a brisk pace to the narration. It is a matter of taste; I suppose you are the author.

The comma before 'which' is another example of parenthetical element, but is more tricky. The difference between [non/restrictive relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Restrictive_or_non-restrictive_relative_clauses) refers to [*adjectival* clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause#Relative_.28adjectival.29_clause)

**(1)** The builder, *who erects very fine houses,* will make a large profit. (non-restrictive)
(2) The builder who erects very fine houses will make a large profit. (restrictive)

You can see that in sentence **(1)** the clause is enclosed by commas, (commas act as parentheses, hence: *parenthetical* element) , and that is why it is call *'adjectival'*
Here the relative clause is not adjectival: non-restrictive/parenthetical clauses are usually embedded in the main clause, and, moreover, it constitutes a **relevant part** of the sentence, try to suppress it and see what happens! Therefore the comma it is **not** necessary, and can be omitted expecially if you omit the commas around 'on that morning'. In fact the whole clause is surely more essential than one of its parts.

> As they passed the cathedral, they rode alongside the River Irwell, 
>   (which **on that morning** had a thick layer of fog blanketing the black
>   waters).

In this version of the sentence, suggested in another answer, the *adverbial (phrase)* 'on that morning' is considered more essential than the whole clause, which is rather odd.

In literature, where commas are also used to convey rhythm and emotions, you have a wide range of possibilities.

Comment: Why do you think *"on that morning"* is a parenthetical element and *"as they passed the cathedral"* is not?  Both of these phrases can be removed without changing the essential meaning of the sentence. (As can the word *"thick"*, which should clearly not be called a parenthetical element; this definition of *"parenthetical element"* is rather useless.) I'd recommend keeping just two commas in this sentence: after *"cathedral"* and before *"which"*.

Comment: @PeterShor, ""(As can the word "*thick*..."",then go ahead, write your answer and put two nice commas around ,thick,!